# Ragged grid of facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some repeated measurements data from cohorts of uneven size.
I’d like to create a plot with facets for individual subjects, with
cohorts grouped on rows – essentially a ragged grid of facets.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

n <- c(3, 4, 3)
k <- 5
y <- t(MASS::mvrnorm(sum(n), rep(0, k), diag(k) * 0.4 + 0.6))

d <- data.frame(
  subjid = c(col(y)),
  cohort = rep(rep(1:3, n), each = k),
  tpt = c(row(y)),
  y = c(y)
)
d$subjid <- sprintf("%d%02d", d$cohort, d$subjid)

head(d)
#>   subjid cohort tpt          y
#> 1    101      1   1 -1.3375592
#> 2    101      1   2 -1.0513184
#> 3    101      1   3 -0.3968382
#> 4    101      1   4 -1.5878445
#> 5    101      1   5 -1.2790463
#> 6    102      1   1 -0.3494143
```

I’ve tried `facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()`, but neither result is satisfactory.
For wrap, I end up with subjects from different cohorts mixing on rows:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ subjid, ncol = max(n))
```

[image]

For grid, I end up with too many facets:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(cohort ~ subjid)
```

[image]

I also tried patchwork, which gets me the correct grouping,
but not alignment of the facets across rows.

```r
library(patchwork)

lapply(unique(d$cohort), \(c) {
  d <- subset(d, cohort == c)
  ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(cohort ~ subjid)
}) |> wrap_plots(ncol = 1)
```

[image]

How can I create a ragged grid of facets in ggplot2?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the [ggh4x](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html) package with facets?

Comment: Thanks @Quinten, that ended up working out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: [ggragged](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggragged) is now also on CRAN.

---

I made an experimental package [ggragged](https://mikmart.github.io/ggragged/) for creating these layouts easily:

```r
library(ggragged) # remotes::install_github("mikmart/ggragged")

ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() +
  facet_ragged_rows(vars(cohort), vars(subjid), labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() +
  facet_ragged_cols(vars(subjid), vars(cohort), labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`facet_manual()` from [ggh4x](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggh4x) can create such a layout.
However, some preparation needs to go into creating the grid layout manually first:

```r
library(ggh4x)

design_ragged_rows <- function(data, rows, cols) {
  facets <- unique(data[c(rows, cols)])
  facet_id <- seq_len(nrow(facets))
  
  groups <- split(facet_id, facets[rows], drop = TRUE)
  n <- lengths(groups)
  i <- rep(seq_along(n), n)
  j <- sequence(n)
  
  design <- matrix(NA_integer_, max(i), max(j))
  replace(design, cbind(i, j), facet_id)
}

design <- design_ragged_rows(d, "cohort", "subjid")
design
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3   NA
#> [2,]    4    5    6    7
#> [3,]    8    9   10   NA

ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() +
  facet_manual(vars(subjid), design = design)
```

[image]

Cohort strips can be added with the `strip` argument (thanks @teunbrand):

```r
ggplot(d, aes(tpt, y)) + geom_line() +
  facet_manual(
    vars(cohort, subjid),
    design = design,
    strip = strip_split(position = c("left", "top"))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: You can add cohort strips by using `facet_manual(vars(cohort, subjid), design = design,                strip = strip_split(c("left", "top")))`.